# knife ec2 create server logging

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

I'm using knife ec2 create server with a run list to create a server and also bootstrap it for initial use.

During my bootstrapping I run a bash command using here docs. This base script has echos in it to report on status, which is nice for following progress.

The only time I see the output is when there is a failure.

is there a way to turn on output and/or get the output written to a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually write the output any command to a file using STDOUT. Here is how to do it.

```
your_command > file_name.log 2>&1
```

Thats it. Try it out, let me knw if you have any problem

Comment: While this does work, it is not ideal. I'm looking for a solution using chef that will print output of recipes even on success, not to go rewrite a bunch of recipes.. Also, under other circumstances it might be preferable to have the output go to console